# Angular.js (possible bug) - objects attribute return undefined on a single item view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

i have a poll application with 2 views, list view and single item view. these are the init functions in the angular client controller

```
        // Poll List
        $scope.pollList = function(){
            $scope.votes = Votes.query({
                userId:Authentication.user._id
            });             
            $scope.polls = Polls.query();
        };

        // View Poll
        $scope.findOne = function(){
            $scope.votes = Votes.query({
                userId:Authentication.user._id
            });
            $scope.poll = Polls.get({
                pollId: $stateParams.pollId
            });
            $scope.categories = Categories.query();
            $scope.languages = Languages.query();
            $scope.pollItem($scope.poll);
        };

        // Poll Item
        $scope.pollItem = function(poll){
            $scope.pollVoted(poll);
            $scope.countPollVotes(poll);
            for (var i = 0; i < poll.poll_options.length; i++){
                $scope.optionItem(poll,poll.poll_options[i]);
            };
        };
```

both the list view and the single view initiate a pollItem function in each poll object. in the list view everything works good - each poll object passes the pollItem function without an error. but in the single poll view im recieveing errors, namely, that the diffrent attributes of the poll (i.e user, comments, poll_options) are returning undefined! allthough when i console.log the poll object i can see them all there. please help! im aware to the fact that it sounds a bit vague but im not sure which other details to provide.. im stuck a couple of days on this problem and no answer to be found.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your issue is. Can you create a plunker that shows your issue? Or at least clarify where in your code you are having an issue.